# Confluence content REST api result size mismatch issue

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

trying confluence rest api to read comments for given page - from below rest calls but its giving different result when add `expand (_expandable) body.view`

Total : comment for given ID (some page id) is 28

Request 1) able to get 25 in first and rest 3 with next link
Request 2) not able to get 25 in first call

---

### Request 1:

```
/rest/api/content/ID/child/comment
```

Results:

```
{
  results : [ from 1 to 25 ],
"start": 0,
    "limit": 25,
    "size": 25,
    "_links": {
        "self": "/rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?limit=25",
        "next": "/rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?limit=25&start=25",
        "base": "baseurl",
        "context": ""
    }
```

---

### Request 2: only changed to add expand

```
/rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?expand=body.view
```

Results:

```
{
  results : [ from 1 to 0],
"start": 0,
    "limit": 25,
    "size": 20,
    "_links": {
        "self": "/rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?limit=25",
        "next": "***0/***rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?limit=25&start=25",
        "base": "baseurl",
        "context": ""
    }
```

Any suggestion why ?

Comment: also i do get additional "0" in front of next url in response for example - not sure what that mean -- "next": "0/rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?limit=25&start=25"

Comment: not sure its api bug or thats how "expand=body.view" behave - version am using is confluence-5.6.1

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. It's still a work in progress, but may have been fixed in 5.7. I suggest filing an issue at https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/CRA

Comment: Thanks skaffman - its looks other work around i found it to use

Comment: Thanks skaffman - it looks like bug ----  other work around i found it to use expand in second call first call without expand and when it say or return next link use expand - /rest/api/content/ID/child/comment?expand=body.view -- only disadvantage is that i have to make additional call to pull body for those there is no body -

Comment: another bug i found with api is that - Size its say 8 - how ever in those 8 one record came twice (technically its only 7) - not sure how many more am going to find.